# How to use Alpha channel in GOP Framebuffers?

Tags: c, graphics, operating-system

While developing an operating system, I can draw a shape with any color with 0xFFFFFFFF, All RGB Channels are working but Alpha channel is not working why?

And How can I make Alpha channel work?

I am using GOP Framebuffers;

`void PlotPixel(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, unsigned int color) { buffer->baseAddress + (x*4) + (y * buffer->PPSL * 4) = color; }`

`PlotPixel(400, 450, 0x6EFFFFFF);`

https://wiki.osdev.org/GOP

Comment: have no idea about UEFI or GOP ... but does you buffer support HW alpha blending ? if not then you need to mix the colors on your own according to rules (blend function) you want to use  so if you got original color `c0` (present in buffer) and want to draw `c1` over it then you have to do for example `... = ( c0*(255-alpha) + c1*alpha )/255;`  where `/255` can be approximated by `>>8` and multiplication can be done with LUT on per channel basis.